# My question had three upvotes, suddenly it is zero. What is going on?

Tags: discussion, support, votes

I recently asked a question [pause youtube-dl when network is disconnected and resume when it is connected again](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/627521/206574) (which currently has an open bounty). Yesterday it had 3 upvotes. Today, I checked and it has 0.

Can anyone please check what is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question still has 2 upvotes. One upvote was removed and two downvotes were added which brings the total score to 0. Once you reach 1000 reputation, you become an "established user" which brings the [ability to see vote counts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user). On your question, this looks like:

[image: Screenshot showing the +2 and -2 vote count of the question]

Next, if you check [your own profile page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/206574/blueray) and click on the "Activity" tab and then the "Reputation" tab, you will see an "unupvote"; someone removed their upvote:

[image: Screenshot of the OP's reputation tab showing the removed upvote]

So, in summary, one vote was removed but the other two are still there, just not so easily visible.

As for what's wrong with your question, I am afraid only the two people who downvoted can answer that. I don't see any obvious issues myself, and I just upvoted it.